# How to Create Multiple thread instantly in ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Is it possible to create and execute multiple threads at a same time?

### e.g. Creating 2 threads requires to write Thread.new 2 times and then .join line. but what if i want to create 50 threads doing same thing. Is it possible to create 50 thread without typing each thread separately?

for eg.

to print "a" on screen twice but "instantly" at a same time, I need this lines:

t1=Thread.new{print "a"}

t2=Thread.new{print "a"}

t1.join

t2.join

## output ==> aa

---

but what if i want to print "a" 50 times on screen instantly without typing thread.new 50 times?
How can i do this, creating and executing 50 threads instantly, please help.

Comment: What are all these threads running? Are they 50 different methods? If you can put the thread methods into an enumerable structure, or construct their names algorithmically, then you can easily do a `Thread.new(...)` in an enumeration loop.

Comment: to print "a" on screen twice but instantly at a same time, I need this lines:
-------------------------------
t1=Thread.new{print "a"}
t2=Thread.new{print "a"}
t1.join
t2.join
#output ==> aa
----------------------------------
but what if i want to print "a" 50 times on screen instantly without typing thread.new 50 times?
How can i do this, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use an array:

```
threads = Array.new
50.times { threads << Thread.new { print "a" } }
50.times { threads.pop.join }
```